# Make text wrap at width of large no-wrap div

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML:

```html
foo foo foo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo
foo

<div style="white-space:nowrap;">bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar </div>
```

So, the line with `bar` doesn't wrap and makes the browser scroll horizontally, but the `foo` text wraps. But their widths are not aligned.

How can I make sure that the `foo` block takes the width of the `bar` line?

Comment: `display: inline-block` will make the text stay a solid block

Comment: @Simplicius do you have a link to the spec?

Comment: There is no "foo block" to style here, you only have the body element with a text node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foo text node cannot be styled (it's only a node, not an element). Your only option as far as I know is to style the `<body>` element. You can make it scale to the width of its contents using `width: min-content`.

```css
body {
    width: min-content;
}
```

```html
foo foo foo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo foofoo
foo

<div style="white-space:nowrap;">bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar </div>
```

Comment: display: inline-block; would be better and more supported

Comment: That’s given you have an actual element to apply this to, isn’t it? The way I read the question, OP is trying to style a text node being the direct descendant of the body element.

Comment: you apply it to the body instead of width:min-content

Comment: That doesn't seem to cut it for me, neither in FF nor Chrome.

Comment: Actually it’ a inside a div, so you could extend your answer with a surrounding div.

Answer (score -1):

You are removing the automatic line breaks with the style in `white-space: nowrap;`.

Try removing it if you have no specific reason to have it here!